# HSTS Header present but in security tab HSTS: disabled

Tags: hsts, strict-transport-security

We are using Tenable to identify security vulnerabilities. Missing HSTS was identified recently. Our server is Apache for ui and spring boot for backend .

The HSTS header is present in the response headers but in the security tab it indicated disabled.

My config for the virtual host in httpd.conf is as follows:

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"

Question: How do I make this change show up for Firefox and Tenable?

Thank you.

Comment: For Firefox I would do a search.  I found [one site](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/) that talks about how to clear this information in Firefox but I have not tested it.  For Tenable, given what your company is paying for that I would reach out to them.  You may want to also verify the HSTS with one of the free tools online just to make sure.

Comment: @stdunbar, thank you for response tried that with firefox but still seeing hsts disabled even with the header is present. but what i saw  during my tests that the call to apis in the same host as apache have (header present, hsts enabled) and calls to api hosted in diffrent machines(header present, hsts disabled). Do i perhaps missing some configuration for apache. thank you